# creating a udev rule to get data from a symlink for a usb barcode scanner(ls2208)

Tags: linux, barcode-scanner, udev, evdev

I have this udev rule which creates the symlink
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{product}=="Symbol Bar Code Scanner", SYMLINK+="scanner1"`
but when i cat the symlink like so `cat /dev/scanner1`
I get this `File: /dev/scanner1   <BINARY> │ Size: 0 B` I was hoping for somthing like when you do `cat /dev/input/mice`

ps: thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I needed to use ACTION=="add" when I did that and changed the subsystem to input it worked and I could see scanner output by using `cat barcode scanner symlink`